# Intermittent Rewrite Problems

Tags: 404-error, rewrite-rules

I have a few custom rewrites on a site I have developed.

I'm having a couple of issues:

1. The rewrites don't work properly without using
   "flush_rewrite_rules(true)" directly following their setup. It
   doesn't matter if I save the permalinks, the code is required or a
   lot of the links stop functioning properly.
2. I'm intermittently
   getting 404 errors, maybe 10% of the time on certain rewrite rules.

When things load properly I get...

```
matched rule and query
'^location/([^/]*)/details/([^/]*)/?$'

matched query
'location=naples&details=testimonials'
```

When I get a 404 I get ...

```
matched rule and query
'(.+?)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$'

matched query
'category_name=location%2Fnaples%2Fdetails&name=testimonials&page='
```

These both are based on the same URL, I simply refresh the page and the problem occurs.

```
/location/naples/details/testimonials/
```

Here is the function I use to setup my custom rewrite rules

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^browse/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=1739&state=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^blog/location/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=84&location_taxonomy=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^blog/location/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?page_id=84&location_taxonomy=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^blog/location/([^/]*)/category/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=84&location_taxonomy=$matches[1]&category=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^blog/location/([^/]*)/category/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?page_id=84&location_taxonomy=$matches[1]&category=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^blog/location/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?name=$matches[2]&location_taxonomy=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^location/([^/]*)/details/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&details=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^location/([^/]*)/details/events/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?event=$matches[2]&location_taxonomy=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    flush_rewrite_rules( true );
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what action is `custom_rewrite_rules` hooked to?

Comment: custom rewrite_rules is hooked to 'init'

Comment: there's definitely something wrong if you're rules disappear, `flush_rewrite_rules` should certainly not be called on every request. have you tested with all plugins disabled and one of the default themes active?